# MYSQL 1265 Data truncated for column X at row Y1262 Row Ywas truncated; it contained more data than there were input columns

Tags: mysql, sql

This warning appears when I try and load csv
I create the table

```
CREATE TABLE Transactions(
 Transaction_Date DATE ,
 Customer VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 Customer_Name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 Country VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 Product VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 Product_Name VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 Platform VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 Quantity VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL,
 Price VARCHAR(255) DEFAULT NULL
);
```

Load script

```
LOAD DATA LOCAL INFILE'C:\\Users\\valer\\Documents\\sql\\transactions_utf8_2018.csv'
 INTO TABLE Transactions
 FIELDS TERMINATED BY ','
 OPTIONALLY ENCLOSED BY '"'
 LINES TERMINATED BY '\r\n'
 IGNORE 1 LINES
 (@date_Transaction_Date, Customer, Customer_Name, Country, Product, Product_Name, Platform, 
 Quantity, Price)
 SET Transaction_Date = STR_TO_DATE(@date_Transaction_Date, '%d/%m/%Y'
);
```

The problem appears when a line with multiple **"** appears.
Something like this

```
10/10/2014,3007,DUANE READE CORP.,UNITED STATES,NADBAS08490S21522926,"Message Manager 
\Ilumin\""""",Windows,63,25515
```

I cannot just edit the whole csv file to remove the unnecessary ", is there a way I can escape it as there are quite a few lines containing multiple " signs

Comment: *is there a way I can escape it as there are quite a few lines containing multiple " signs* No problems, process the value by the same way as for `Transaction_Date` column. PS. The CSV value for `Product_Name` is not correct. You have `\"""""` substring. 1st '"' is a char quoted with backslash, next 2 pairs are 2 quoted (doubled) dquote chars... and the whole value have no final dquote char. So all next values are treated as not values for next columns but as a part of this column...

Comment: *I cannot just edit the whole csv file* If so then load the whole line into one variable then parse all columns values.

Comment: How would I assign the whole line to a variable and separate each value instead of assigning  each value to a variable like I do with `Transaction_Date`

Comment: *How would I assign the whole line to a variable* Put only one variable into assignment list, set fiedls terminator to the char which is absent in the file with guarantee. *and separate each value instead* Extract needed part from the whole row value with common string functions.